# Typescript conditional return type based on arguments values

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have a function `sum` which takes two arguments (x, y) and produces an object with following conditions:

- If sum of x & y gives an even number, return object has `sum` & `isEven` keys, where `isEven = true` & `sum = x + y`
- If sum of x & y gives an odd number, return object has only `isEven` key which is false

```
type Props = { x: number, y: number };
type ReturnEven = { isEven: true, sum: number };
type ReturnOdd = { isEven: false, sum?: never };

const fn = ({ x, y }: Props): ReturnEven | ReturnOdd =>
  x + y % 2 === 0
    ? { isEven: true, sum: x + y }
    : { isEven: false }

const { sum, isEven } = fn({ x: 2, y: 2 });

if (isEven) {
  // Line below gives following type:
  // const sum: number | undefined
  console.log(sum)
}
```

How can I enforce `number` type on `sum` variable in "if" scope?

Codesandbox for convenience:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-rgb-d59vmz?file=/src/index.tsx

P.s. I saw an approach with overloading which I think is not applicable here since return type depends on arguments values, not arguments types?

Comment: You can't. TypeScript won't narrow a variable based on a test of a different variable. I've seen this come up before, I'll try to find the earlier question on it.

Comment: (But you can do `const result = fn({ x: 2, y: 2 });` and `if (result.isEven)`; in the `if` body, `result.sum` will have the type `number`.) (Side note: You don't need `sum?: never`.) [Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NVa1Bw)

Comment: This would also have little use because the argument value will likely be dynamic, not static.

Comment: @youdateme - That's okay, narrowing with `if` is dynamic.